Setting storageClass on Gitlab helmcart for Postgres, Minio, etc
I'm trying to deploy the gitlab helm chart:
https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/

But when I updated the values.yml Postgres deployment with a custom storageClass the PVC does not show a storageClass has been set.
...
postgresql:
  persistence:
    storageClass: ebs-sc
    size: 8Gi
...

helm install --namespace gitlab -f values.yml gitlab gitlab/gitlab

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
  namespace: gitlab
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp3
  iopsPerGB: "10"
  fsType: ext4
reclaimPolicy: Delete

My configuration files are above , postgres is part of the larger values.yml file found:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/blob/master/values.yaml?ref_type=heads

Read this from gitlab and it shows the postgres config above
https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/storage.html

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/storage/helm_options.yml


Realized I missed a step in
https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/storage.html
Needed to run
kubectl patch storageclass CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}
which seems to just override anything set in the values.yml.

Basically you made your storage class a default storage class, so if not explicitly mentioned otherwise in the manifests or helm charts, kubernetes will use the default storage class. The problem for me is that gitlab helm chart does not offer the possibility to configure the storage class for minio (I did not try postgres). However, you can change the storage class of other components like gitaly in the helm chart using gitlab.gitaly.persistence.storageClass. Maybe by using the minio subchart it's possible to change the storage class in the gitlab helm.
